# Send money to a smart contract using solidity

Tags: solidity

I wrote the following code. I know it sends the ether from the contract balance but It doesn't allow me to send ether to the contract`s address.

How can I change the method so it will allow sending ether to the contract?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;
contract MyFirstContract
{
    function() external payable { }

    function send(address payable _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) 
    {
        require(_value <= address(this).balance);
        _to.transfer(_value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code

Comment: what do you mean by "sending ethers to the contract"? is it external contract or self
If it's an external contract then you code should work fine. If you want to recieve ether and store it in self you can just call payback function by adding value

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't allow you to send ether to a contract's address could be there is no fallback function in that contract.

If you want to send ether to a contract without calling any of its functions, you need to have a fallback function in that contract to receive ether.

Add this function in the contract which you want to send ether to:

```
function () external payable {}
```

Here is a more detailed version: [fallback](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#fallback-function)